# Add some styling and change link color on hover: CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

I have a fieldset with some hyperlinks and styling in CSS

```
.fieldset-start {
styling code here
}
```

And code what to do on mouse hover

```
.fieldset-start:hover
{
some on-hover styling code
}
```

What I want to do is change links color and remove underline on hover.

I currently have

```
.fieldset-start:hover A:link {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

but it doesn't work. What's right way to do that?

Comment: Please post a complete code example, including your HTML for example. And a jsFiddle.net example is always helpful.

Comment: The solution is change .fieldset-start:hover A:link to .fieldset-start:hover a. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2JW32/

**CSS**

```
fieldset:hover a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <div>Hello World</div>
    <a href="http://google.com">Test 1</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">Test 2</a>
</fieldset>
```

You may want to check that another selector with greater specificity is not preventing the desired effect.

Also remember that `:link` [applies to links which have not been visited](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3alink). If you need to match visited links as well, you can use the more generic `a` selector, or add a second selector for `a:visited`.